# How does a user of an AppEngine app upload a large file if the app is using GCS?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

With the old blobstore, blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler took care of long requests, for example the user could upload a 100mb file, taking 2 minutes

However I've not seen any example or document anywhere that explains a similar process using Google Cloud Storage, all examples provided just upload sample text files from appengine to gcs, there are no "user -> appengine -> gcs" examples, hope I didn't miss anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload a file to GCS using the blobstore API by specifying the argument `gs_bucket_name` of the function [`create_upload_url`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_upload_url).